# Nested views with angular with ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How i can insert login in index and info in login with ui.router in angular?

I need to use different views according to url is used, for example when you enter login and upload this view for the driver here the html is injected, and for other cases the view shows the menu and sidebar.

## index.html

```
<div ui-view="principal"></div>
```

## login.html

```
<div ui-view="info"></div>
```

I try with this but don't works, anybody can help me.

```
$stateProvider
   .state('login', 
          {url: '/login',
           views: {'principal':{templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
                            controller: 'LoginController',
                            controllerAs: 'login'},
          {'info':{templete: '<div>HELLO</div>'}}

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Nested States & Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) as follows:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', { // www.domain.com/#/
        url: '/',
        template: '<h1>Index view</h1><div ui-view></div>'
    })
    .state('index.login', { // www.domain.com/#/login
        url: '/login'
        template: '<h2>Login view</h2><div ui-view></div>'
    })
    .state('index.login.info', { // www.domain.com/#/login/info
        url: '/info'
        template: '<p>Info view :)<p>'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('login', 
          {url: '/login',
           views: {'principal':{templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
                            controller: 'LoginController',
                            controllerAs: 'login'},
          {'info':{template: '<div>HELLO</div>'}}
});
```

If this works, then it's because you misspelled the word "template" in the 'info' section.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution, principal is the layout that use and info@foo is where inject content. thanks for answers!

```
    $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
            'info@home': {
              templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
              controller: 'MainController',
              controllerAs: 'main'
            },
             'principal' : {
              templateURL: 'principal.html'}}
          })
          .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
             'info@login', {
               templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
               controller: 'LoginController',
               controllerAs: 'login'
            },
            'principal': "login.html"}
          });
```